# package-info.java compilation on UNIX server

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using JAXB unmarshalling to parse through a XML file. Have created two JAXB objects with different packages which means two package-info.java files are available.

Compilation of both the package-info.java also goes through on Eclipse. Have an issue on UNIX server. The java file names should be unique. How can i now maintain multiple package-info.java which is required for proper namespace.

Code of package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.com/done/", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns = { @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix = "done",namespaceURI = "http://www..com/done/" )})
package com.ui.done.one;
```

Code of another package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.com/done/", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns = { @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix = "done",namespaceURI = "http://www..com/done/" )})
package com.ui.done.two;
```

Help me on how to maintain multiple package-info.java but with a unique name.

Java version is "1.7.0.08"

Answer (score 0):

You may only have one `package-info` class per package in Java.  Based on your question you would the following file structure:

- /com

  - /ui

    - /done

      - /one

        - package-info.java
      - /two

        - package-info.java